# UML multi object class: Use singular or plural?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

What is the correct way to name a multiobject in UML (class diagram). Is singular or plural form used for the name, stereotype, etc.?

Example:
[image: Plural vs Singular]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use singular. The multiplicity is often verified by the diagram associations.

See a similar answer here in Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032474/how-to-show-multiplicities-in-uml-object-diagrams

Comment: Thanks. Even though the other question is about instance diagrams I can see that this kind of "best practice" is applicable to static class diagrams as well (which are my primary focus).